# Pandoc: Using standardized unicode Emoji

Tags: unicode, rendering, markdown, pandoc, emoticons

I want to use `flag: Japan` emoticon with unicode `U+1F1EF U+1F1F5` as defined in the standard [Full Emoji List, v12.0](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html), inside markdown (rendered with Pandoc).

Given that this Emoticon is not defined inside Pandoc sourcecode: [pandoc/Emoji.hs at master · jgm/pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Emoji.hs), how can I use this inside the document? Or how can I define this in the Pandoc Source Code?

> **If possible please suggest a general solution that can parse multiple unicode emoji's, such as `:thermometer:` for , `:jp:` for .**

An extensible code would read a csv file or data structure inside lua file:

```
jp,
thermometer,
```

and make string substitutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more general than @tarleb solution.

```lua
ReplacementTable={
      [":jp:"] = "", 
      [":in:"] = "", 
      [":thermometer:"] = "", 
      [":snow_capped_mountain:"] = "  ", 
      [":beach:"] = "  ", 
      [":national_park:"] = "  ", 
      [":money_bag:"] = "  ", 
      [":see_no_evil_monkey:"] = "  ", 
      [":hear_no_evil_monkey:"] = "  ", 
      [":speak_no_evil_monkey:"] = "  "}

function Str (s)
  return pandoc.Str(s.text:gsub("%S+", ReplacementTable))
end
```

Comment: Nice!  (first line is duplicated though) It will be a tiny bit faster to define `ReplacementTable` outside the function.

Comment: @tarleb Thank you so much! I learnt so much on my first day of lua. But it would be great if our code can use pandoc abstract syntax tree (AST) as this does a stupid replacement of the text. Although it is fine, but it is stupid. I mean that this will blindly replace the text (even if its not meant to be emoji).

Comment: We are using the AST, if in a rather primitive way. This becomes clear if one uses a custom emoji in a code block `:beach:` : it will not be replaced, as text in code is represented by a different element than other text (`Code` vs. `Str`; replace `Str` with `Code` in the filter to make it work on inline code). Pandoc handles emoji when reading, which allows to handle `:emoji:` and `\:emoji\:` differently. However, both look the same in the AST, so there is no way to distinguish the two in a filter. The smartest way would be to amend pandoc's internal emoji table.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are counter indications against using the emoji directly, one could simply use the unicode representation.

The alternative would be to add this feature via a [pandoc Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html). Save the following code into a file `flag-jp.lua` and pass it to pandoc via `--lua-filter=flag-jp.lua`. The file must be stored as UTF-8.

```
function Str (s)
  return pandoc.Str(s.text:gsub(':jp:', ''))
end
```

The flag can then be inserted by writing `:jp:` in Markdown.

Comment: Your answer does work! Can I request you if it is possible to make it more general function, in which we could supply multiple custom Emojis. Please see the latest EDIT of the question.